# Нескрываемая клавиатура а Android

Tags: java, android

Есть `EditText`, при запуске фрагмента вызывается клавиатура, но меняется кнопка назад на скрытие клавиатуры. Как бы от этого избавиться? Т.е. чтобы по кнопке назад - был переход на предыдущий фрагмент, а не скрытие клавиатуры.

Comment: "Т.е. чтобы по кнопке назад - был переход на предыдущий фрагмент, а не скрытие клавиатуры." такого не припомню, сделайте чтоли иную клавиатуру и заблокируйте текущую(странное у вас приложение что нарушает стандарты).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно повесить на активити, откуда вы управляете фрагментами перезаписанный метод:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 // Не скрывать клавиатуру и вызвать нужный фрагмент
 super.onBackPressed();  
}
```